# How to change all element's font family wpf-xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, element, font-family

I use MetroDark theme.

I use this code in xaml :

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/MetroDark/MetroDark.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/MetroDark/MetroDark.MSControls.Toolkit.Implicit.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" >
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B titr" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Nazanin" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

font family was changed correctly but the background color was changed too.

I just want to change the font family and font size, and another property (such as: background, border etc) and get effect from default theme (MetroDark).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

set base style in `BasedOn` attribute like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
```

this way custom style inherits all settings from base style and can override some of them